# Why does Yeoman generator not work when installed through npm?

Tags: github, npm, yeoman, symlink

### Code

- **GitHub version**: https://github.com/trevordmiller/generator-code-deck
- **npm version**: https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-code-deck

### Background

I have built a Yeoman generator which is working perfectly locally (using `npm link` after cloning the repo from GitHub). However, when I `npm publish` the generator to npm and install it via `npm install -g generator-code-deck`, running the generator throws `no such file or directory` and `cannot find module` errors:

[image]

[image]

These errors don't make sense to me, because 1. the files and folders are obviously there (as shown by the screenshot doodles) and 2. the generator is working via a symbolic link to the local repo; why should the npm package be any different?

I have been searching online to find an answer but I can't find anything. **Does anyone know why these errors are happening when trying to install via npm, but not via a symbolic link? Does anyone know how to fix this** so that I can release the official npm version of the Yeoman generator? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're not publishing all files to npm.

This can be caused by a `.npmignore` file or by the `files` key of your `package.json`.

Comment: There was an empty `.npmignore` file, so I removed it just to check.
The `files` key (in `package.json`) only had listed the `generators` folder, which is all that is needed...so I don't think that would be the problem. However, I removed that from the `package.json`, bumped the version, and updated the npm package with `npm publish`. After re-installing the `npm` package via `npm install -g generator-code-deck`, I am still getting the same error:
`ENOENT, no such file or directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-code-deck/generators/app/templates/.gitignore'`

Comment: If you take a look at the GitHub repo, you can see that the `package.json` no longer has a `file` key, and that there is no `.npmignore` file: https://github.com/trevordmiller/generator-code-deck. I don't know what else would be different about the npm package...any other ideas?